# Subaru Forester OBD Scan Codes "P0130" and "P0130 P"

Tags: subaru, obd-ii, o2-sensor, forester, p0130

My 2002 Forester Check Engine light is on. I connected an Autel MaxiScan MS300 OBD-II scan tool and got indication for two codes. Browsing through the codes, it reads `P0130` and `P0130 P`.

The first one is easily found to be the O2 sensor problem:

> O2 Sensor Circuit Malfunction (Bank 1 Sensor 1)

However, I could not determine what the second code means. Obviously it is closely related to the `P0130` code, but the tool specifically indicates two codes rather than one.

So, any idea what this `P` suffix can indicate? The tool user manual is not helpful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pending code? The user manual for your device says it should say "PD" for pending codes, so maybe not.  "P0130 P" isn't a valid DTC for your vehicle so pending code is really all that makes sense.

More specific to your model P0130 is front oxygen sensor circuit range/performance problem (Lean)

Possible causes:

- Open wire to O2 Sensor
- Short to ground in O2 sensor wire
- Exhaust Leak
- Faulty Sensor

Comment: Mmm... why would it be pending, when the actual code is displayed first??!

Comment: @ysap The code without the P at the end is a history code, meaning that that code has happened in an earlier drive cycle. The pending code means it's a current code.